# syntax of mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a stored procedure in MySQL, but it gives me a syntax error.

Here is query:

```
delimiter //
create procedure PostToTimeline (in txt text, in BY int, in FORR int)
begin if BY = FORR then
insert into posts (Body,UserID_BY,UserID_FOR) values(txt,BY,FORR);
else
insert into posts (Body,UserID_BY,UserID_FOR)
select txt, friends.UserID,friends.FriendID
from friends where friends.UserID = BY and friends.FriendID = FORR;
end//
delimiter;
```

What is problem?

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using a reserved keyword. `BY` is a reserved keyword. The best solution is to change it rather than escaping it.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE PostToTimeline 
(
    IN txt TEXT, 
    IN BYParam INT, 
    IN FORR INT
)
BEGIN
    IF BYParam = FORR THEN
       INSERT INTO posts (Body, UserID_BY, UserID_FOR) 
       VALUES(txt, BYParam, FORR);
    ELSE
       INSERT INTO posts (Body, UserID_BY, UserID_FOR)
       SELECT txt, friends.UserID, friends.FriendID
       FROM friends 
       WHERE friends.UserID = BYParam AND
             friends.FriendID = FORR;
    END IF;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

- [MySQL Reserved Keywords List](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

Another problem is that you have no `end if` in your `if-else` statement.

Comment: yor new code gives me error
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PROPCEDURE PostToTimeline ( IN txt TEXT, IN BYParam INT, IN F' at line 1

Comment: `PROCEDURE` not `PROPCEDURE`. sorry for the typo.